# Selenium + Java | Improving a wait time

Tags: java, selenium, wait

I'm doing some automation work and would like some input/advice on how to shave a couple seconds from a WebDriverWait sentence I'm using.

Basically I have this which I call several times throughout my code

```
  public void waitForLoadingCurtainToDisappear() {
    new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 30).until(ExpectedConditions.
        invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".loader-curtain")));
  }
```

It pretty much does as it says. As the code moves through the flow and the pages a loading curtain shows up when new info needs to be loaded (payment method, billing address form, etc). This works almost perfectly but it always wait 2 or 3 seconds after the loading screen disappeared before performing whatever actions I want it to do.

So!, any input on how I could improve this? I'm pretty sure I'm missing an option to specify the polling frequency but can't seem to find one that does that.

Comment: You may want to read & try what the optional third parameter does [`WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html#WebDriverWait%28org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,%20long%29)

Comment: Thanks. I was actually reading up on that and tried it but didn't seem to work. Dunno if I'm using it right or not but I basically added a '500' value as the third parameter for the sleepInMillis but didn't notice any difference.

Comment: in case I get the docs of the superlong constructor right, its 500 by default anyways. Your delay is maybe not Selenium's fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use the [`FluentWait` class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) that allows to adjust the polling interval.